# Import module based on string

Tags: python, scikit-learn, python-import, code-readability

I get a string (model_name) that is indicating what model should be used, 
For example `LinearRegression` or `RANSACRegression`.

So for example if `model_name=="LinearRegression"`, I would need to import this module and to assign it to the model like this:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression 
model=LinearRegression()
```

same if `model_name=="RANSACRegression"`:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import RANSACRegression 
model=RANSACRegression()
```

one can assume that all the models I get are in `sklearn.linear_model`.

Is there a good way to assign the model, without an ugly `if...else`?

I've looked into `importlib` - but didn't find a good way to use it in my case.

Comment: One cheeky way you could do this is through eval. if you do `import sklearn.linear_model` then you could run `model=eval(f"sklearn.linear_model.{model_name}()")`

Comment: I would rather not to use `eval`...

Comment: yeah, probably not the best strategy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found something that works, don't know if it is the best or cleanest solution, but better then `if...else`:

```
linear_model=getattr(__import__('sklearn'),'linear_model')
curr_method=getattr(linear_model,model_name)
model=curr_method()
```

Answer (score 1):

Python modules store all of their attributes in `__dict__`. You can simply access the value using that.

```
model = __import__("sklearn.linear_model").__dict__[model_name]
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me: 
`model = __import__("sklearn.linear_model").__dict__['RANSACRegressor']`
output: `NameError: name 'RANSACRegressor' is not defined`

Comment: Does importing the module work? if so, you can import it, and then do `linear_model.__dict__['RANSACRegressor']`. Try just printing the `__dict__` if that doesn't work and see if you can find what you're looking for as a key. The thing is, it's giving a `NameError` for the type of regression, if it didn't find the attribute, it would give `KeyError`.